# Why am i getting error "eval: syntax error near unexpected token `then'"? BASH

Tags: bash, eval

I have done much research before posting here, as I always do... but I can't for the live of me figure out why I'm getting this error...

```
./test.sh: eval: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
```

`STARTUP` is a variable exported from another script so I included it here for testing purposes.

the `sed` command simply converts the string `{{COMMAND}}` to the variable `${COMMAND}` that's defined outside of this script

```sh
#!/bin/bash

STARTUP="if [ -f entrypoint.sh ]; then {{COMMAND}}; fi;"
EVAL_SCRIPT=`eval echo $(echo ${STARTUP} | sed -e 's/{{/${/g' -e 's/}}/}/g')`

# run the script
${EVAL_SCRIPT}
```

Comment: The eval in the EVAL_SCRIPT= is messing it up.  If you remove the eval from there and make the last line `eval ${EVAL_SCRIPT}` then it works.

Comment: copy/paste your code into https://shellcheck.net and include the proper top-line, ie `#!/bin/bash` (or do you really want `#!/bin/sh` ?) Good luck.

Comment: It seems weird to be executing all this code in subshells.  Instead of `echo $(echo ${STARTUP} | sed -e 's/{{/${/g' -e 's/}}/}/g')` you could have just used `echo ${STARTUP} | sed -e 's/{{/${/g' -e 's/}}/}/g'`

Comment: i still dont understand why the 'eval' was messing it up... the answer from Jerry worked for me! so thanks... i guess...

Comment: I think the reason the eval was messing it up is because `eval echo $(echo ${STARTUP} | sed -e 's/{{/${/g' -e 's/}}/}/g')` ends up being `eval echo if [ -f entrypoint.sh ]; then {{COMMAND}}; fi;`  And the first command is `eval echo if [ -f entrypoint.sh ]`  So the echo is executed and then the second command is `then {{COMMAND}};` but there hasn't been an if - just an echo.  So the then is invalid.  I am sure we can fix it with quoting things properly.  But we don't really need to because `eval echo $(...)` is redundant and just produces `...` anyway.

Comment: _In general_, this is a really unfortunate approach -- [`eval` is best avoided](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: ...if your goal is to have code only run when a condition is true, encapsulate it in a function. If you want to pass that function _as an argument_ to another function, well, you can do that. So: `only_with_entrypoint() { if [ -f entrypoint.sh ]; then "$@"; fi; }; run_my_command() { whatever code here; }; only_with_entrypoint run_my_command` will run `whatever code here` only if `entrypoint.sh` exists.

Comment: Running `${EVAL_SCRIPT}` as a command on its own  has all the bugs discussed in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), because the earlier parsing stages that `eval` triggers don't happen until _after_ `eval` is actually called, which happens after string-splitting, glob expansion, etc. It's not even equivalent to `script=$(echo "$STARTUP" | sed ...)` and then `eval "$script"`. (If you need me to build a test case that works in the one situation and fails in the other to prove the stated assertion, let me know and I'll do that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run:

```
STARTUP="if [ -f entrypoint.sh ]; then {{COMMAND}}; fi;"
EVAL_SCRIPT=`eval echo $(echo ${STARTUP} | sed -e 's/{{/${/g' -e 's/}}/}/g')`
```

The `$(...)` is evaluated and we end up with:

```
EVAL_SCRIPT=`eval echo if [ -f entrypoint.sh ]; then {{COMMAND}}; fi;`
```

Then the backquoted stuff is executed - these three commands:

- `eval echo if [ -f entrypoint.sh ];`
- `then {{COMMAND}};`
- `fi;`

The first command would run find and would echo `if [ -f entrypoint.sh ];` but then the second command is invalid because we have a then without a preceeding if.  And that's why we get the error.

So if we quote it differently:

```
STARTUP="if [ -f entrypoint.sh ]; then {{COMMAND}}; fi;"
EVAL_SCRIPT=`eval echo \"$(echo ${STARTUP} | sed -e 's/{{/${/g' -e 's/}}/}/g')\"`
```

We get exactly what we wanted assigned to EVAL_SCRIPT: `if [ -f entrypoint.sh ]; then ${COMMAND}; fi;`

There is only one thing left.  You can't execute a variable with just:

```
# run the script
${EVAL_SCRIPT}
```

You need to eval a variable.  So you need:

```
# run the script
eval ${EVAL_SCRIPT}
```

One final note: You don't need all the subshells and evals:

- `` `eval echo "..."` `` is completely redundant: eval executes the echo command and that's completely equivalent to just `` `echo "..."` ``
- `` `echo "..."` `` is completely redundant: the echo is executed and that's completely equivalent to just `...`

So

```
STARTUP="if [ -f entrypoint.sh ]; then {{COMMAND}}; fi;"
EVAL_SCRIPT=`eval echo $(echo ${STARTUP} | sed -e 's/{{/${/g' -e 's/}}/}/g')`
```

is equivalent to just:

```
STARTUP="if [ -f entrypoint.sh ]; then {{COMMAND}}; fi;"
EVAL_SCRIPT=$(echo ${STARTUP} | sed -e 's/{{/${/g' -e 's/}}/}/g')
```

And in the end, this works just fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

STARTUP="if [ -f entrypoint.sh ]; then {{COMMAND}}; fi;"
EVAL_SCRIPT=$(echo ${STARTUP} | sed -e 's/{{/${/g' -e 's/}}/}/g')

# run the script
eval ${EVAL_SCRIPT}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using superfluous indirections and subshells. Your code snippet could be reduced into

```
#!/bin/bash

startup=${STARTUP//'{{'/'${'}
eval "${startup//'}}'/'}'}"
```

Of course, `eval` must be used only with content created by yourself or coming from trusted sources. In particular here, the parameter `STARTUP`, and all parameters which occur as a result of expanding it, must come from the content created by yourself or trusted sources.